# Display JPEG using Response.BinaryWrite

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, binarywriter

I'm displaying an image like this:

```
<img src='counter.asp'>
```

*counter.asp* is doing a hit-counter do determine how often the image was displayed (I'll replace it with a `modrewrite` URL).

The problem: in the *counter.asp* script I need to send the actual `.jpg` image to the browser. How could this be done? I suppose I need to load the image through FSO, and then send it using `Response.BinaryWrite` - any ideas?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

FSO cannot load a binary file, only text. You will need to use a 3th party component.

Comment: The answer below mentioning ADODB.Stream *should* have been the accepted one.

Answer (score 10):

To read and output binary you can simply use the ADODB.Stream object.

See the ADODB.Stream MSDN Library:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675032(VS.85).aspx

Here's an example I found from Experts Exchange as well:

```
Function ReadBinaryFile(strFileName) 
        on error resume next 
        Set oStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream") 
        if Err.Number <> 0 then 
                ReadBinaryFile=Err.Description 
                Err.Clear 
                exit function 
        end if 
        oStream.Type = 1  
        oStream.Open 

        oStream.LoadFromFile strFileName 
        if Err.Number<>0 then 
                ReadBinaryFile=Err.Description 
                Err.Clear 
                exit function 
        end if 
        ReadBinaryFile=oStream.Read 
        oStream.Close 
        set oStream = nothing 
        if Err.Number<>0 then ReadBinaryFile=Err.Description 
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

you can just redirect your `counter.asp` to the image you want..

```
<%
response.redirect("/virtual/path/to/yourimage.jpg")
%>
```