# Return an image using ASP, not .NET

Tags: asp-classic

Using traditional ASP how can I return an image from a query.

I want to use an image on a web page for tracking purposes, so for example I might have a page containing:

```
<img src="../cgi-bin/getimage.asp?user1234&page=1232" WIDTH="1" HEIGHT="1">
```

Where GetImage.ASP would record the passed details and return a transparent GIF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use response.binarywrite to give an image as an output in your getimage.asp. If you store the image as a BLOB in database, or if you read the image from a file, get it in a stream and send it in the response using binarywrite method.

You can see this post: [Display JPEG using Response.BinaryWrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481067/classic-asp-display-jpg-using-response-binarywrite)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response :-)